# JavaFX: Can I access Nodes it contains?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2

So I have a `BorderPane` that has a `TextArea` that is set in the centre. It displays information about the current year's sales:

```
public static BorderPane addTransactionPanel() {

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setPrefSize(500, 320);
    final String[] monthName = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

    final TextArea middle = new TextArea();
    middle.setPrefRowCount(1000);
    middle.setEditable(false);

    pane.setBottom(addBox);
    pane.setCenter(middle);

    for (int i = 2; i < li.get(index).getIncomeBook().getExpense().size(); i++) {
        if (li.get(index).getIncomeBook().getExpense().get(i).getDate().getYear() == year) {
                middle.appendText("New expense of: $" + moneyDisplay(li.get(index).getIncomeBook().getExpense().get(i).getValue()) + " on " + monthName[li.get(index).getIncomeBook().getExpense().get(i).getDate().getMonth() - 1] + "\n");
        }
    }

    return pane;
 }
```

This compares the contents of the IncomeBook's expenses (and the year it was spent on), and if it matches the current year, it appends the text onto the `TextArea`. But now, when I change the year (which is a public variable), I want it to update. I'm trying to create another method:

```
public void updateTransactionPanel(BorderPane transactionPanel){
    // I want to clear transactionPanel.middle and write in it again.
    // Can I access the "middle" Node from another method?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the "middle" Node of transactionPanel from another method, clear it and write in it again.

```
public void updateTransactionPanel(BorderPane transactionPanel){
    TextArea middle = (TextArea) transactionPanel.getCenter();
    middle.setText("Updated transaction panel text");
}
```

Comment: Yep, so it is Stevantti :-)  Edited the typo in my answer to fix it.